# Anybody know how to change my bathroom light bulb case/cover?

Tags: electrical, lighting, bathroom, repair, bulb

I just moved to a month ago and the bulb in my bathroom is dead. So I would like to change the bulb, but I cannot open the bulb case/cover. I try to find screw on the bowl-thingy that caging the bulb, no such screw. Anybody that electrician/handyman know how to open this?

Brand is cetek, but i cannot find any information on the brand.

[image: front view]
[image: side view]
[image: brand = cetek]
[image: back view]

Answer (score 2):

Spin the glass bowl inside of the white halo.